# How to reuse CSS selector?

Tags: css, syntax

I have the following CSS:

```
.foo .bar {
   background: red;
}
```

Which works fine for the following HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">I have a red background</div>
</div>
```

But I can't seem to find a way to reuse the CSS definition when I'm not in a parent/child relationship. For example, how could I apply the same CSS to the following DIV:

```
<div class="???">I want a red background!</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add additional selector with comma (,) as specified in [W3C selectors grouping](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping)

```
.foo .bar, .foobar {
   background: red;
}
```

this would work in both

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">I have a red background</div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="foobar">I want a red background!</div>
```

Comment: Faster, Stronger, Bigger (Daft Punk)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a comma to indicate multiple selectors that a CSS rule should apply to

```
.foo .bar, .??? {
   background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a comma separated list of selectors in the definition:

```
.foo .bar, .otherSelector, #someID{
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.foo .bar, .redback {
     background: red;
}
```

will do a magic with

```
<div class="redback">I want a red background!</div>
```

or get rid of hierarchy and use only

```
.bar {
     background: red;
}
```

which will work both cases

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.foo .bar, .foobar {
   background: red;
}
```

with

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">I have a red background</div>
</div>

<div class="foobar">I want a red background!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ".foo .bar" CSS definition is written expressly for a parent-child (more accurately ancestor-decendent) relationship.

You could write the CSS like this:

```
.alternate-background {
   background: red;
}
```

and the HTML like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="alternate-background">I have a red background</div>
</div>
```

which would allow you also to use this:

```
<div class="alternate-background">I want a red background!</div>
```